# Boot drops to (initramfs) cannot find plymouth

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, plymouth

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a msi laptop. After having made several installation and python updates last session, I cannot boot any longer. Boot drops to `(initramfs)` complaining that it cannot find plymouth.

after entering `exit`, I get:

```
Mising modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) 
ALERT ! UUID=d007a5ab-....7842 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

/scripts/panic/plymouth: line 18: /bin/plymouth: not found

Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox
```

I've tried save-mode boot among other options in BIOS, but to no avail.

Any ideas how to proceed?

By the way: I want to make a fresh ubuntu installation once I can login again, as things seemed to be quite bunched up by now. So, if anyone has suggestions that might alter some options, that would be fine as long as I can recover my files.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could save your files without logging into your old install if your disk is not encrypted. Seems quicker than "repairing" the old install first. Boot from stick and copy everything to an external drive would be my choice.

Comment: thank's. Your suggestion was definitely the right way to go about it. However, it could't solve the problem, since the drive was not even accessible from the bootable stick. It seems, unfortunately there is a bigger issue with this drive which require some more drastic measures, I suppose.